# Thank you for reviewing 20 close votes today!

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, rate-limiting

So I did what I thought was my 40 reviews in the *Close Vote Review Queue* today. However, when I went to see about reviewing other queues, I noticed the message for the *Close Votes* said, ***"Thank you for reviewing 20 close votes today"*** instead of saying the normal **40**. I went and counted my close vote reviews, and it turns out it is only showing ***37***.

Does this have to do with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue ? Did they lessen/throttle the number of reviews or something, since we were getting close to 0 for the fuzzy queue?

Shouldn't it say *Thank you for reviewing 37 close votes today* though, instead of 20 anyways? Or possibly the default 40?

BTW, great job cleaning up that queue people!

[image]

Comment: Since the close review votes dropped to 3 digit, they might have reduced the no. of votes..  I guess so

Comment: Two days ago the queue was almost 7k close votes, but now it becomes under 275. How this happened?

Comment: @ling.s: no new stuff coming in the queue. You should have seen it last week when there was 120k to do. BTW could you explain how is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4203554) an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233/187824). 20 reviews per day is [a limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981/187824) for every review queue. But if the review queue size is over 1000, the review limit increase to 40 reviews per day.

Comment: Does that limit change starts at the SE-day or at the moment the the queue drops below 1000?

Comment: @rene - The limit changes at the moment the queue drops below 1000. As we can see today some reviewers were able to [review 40 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

Comment: Well, that is unfair.

Comment: @rene - Not IMO. Because we review to clean the website whether it id reviewed by me or somebody else. If the queue is drops below 1000, I will be pleased.

Comment: I agree with that but I have a game/goal myself which is to stay ahead on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). If I'm only allowed 20 today where my 'competitors' could have done 40 I'm in a disadvantage. I should be compensated for that. ;-)

Comment: Once we hit 0 more questions will be added again as the maximum 'leave open' votes threshold is lowered a step. You'll probably get a chance again today once that happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Are you saying that making the visible number of queue items low is a psychological incentive to get people to review more? Can we have numbers on the absolute amount of review work done since the change of the queue size?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, it's all a trick. See [Let's burn down the close queue!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223497)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Haha, good to know -- I [had been proposing just that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208680/reset-the-close-vote-queue) and got tons of flak over it that "the mind doesn't work that way" and that "it won't solve anything". Can't say I'm not feeling a tiny bit vindicated :-)

Comment: @rene - It's [40 again](http://stackoverflow.com/review)! And as I noted you have already reviewed remaining. :)