# Don't lower the review limit on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review

I just reviewed 20 items in the close vote queue and got the message

> Thank you for reviewing **20** close votes today; come back in 15 hours to continue reviewing.

Normally this is **40** items but [only if the queue size is over 1000 items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223914/thank-you-for-reviewing-20-close-votes-today).

Can this restriction be removed for Stack Overflow or better the actual queue size be considered since the queue actually contains more items than being displayed?

Comment: It'll go up again soon; probably today and then you can complete another 20. Not worth the developer time, IMHO.

Comment: I think this is probably a one-liner to fix or using another existing query.

Comment: If it's forcing you to take a break, it's doing its job - even though your eagerness is appreciated :]

Comment: @Emracool: Actually it's doing the job wrong since it is taking the wrong number into account.

Comment: Eh. I'd go so far as to call this by-design. Yeah, the number of items is higher, but it's also designed this way for a reason. I can think of a couple gamification reasons as well as other psychological ones.

Comment: While we are in the middle of this queue reduction project, posts with new close votes are not getting reviewed until they get 3 votes or flags, so the sooner we can empty out each bucket the better.  I'm nervous that we're going to see 50 or 60K questions by the time we get to the 1 vote section.  Lowering the limit to 20 reviews when the queue size is artificially lower does not make sense.  I agree that it should be 40 votes until the backlog is completely gone.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of *How come my vote cap for “First Posts” is lower than others?* and why can't I see any close votes on my question?

Comment: @Juegen perhaps it was a flag? I can see no current close votes on this question

Comment: @RichardTingle: Could be. But I would not have thought that a flag already displays that message into a question.

Comment: @juergend it does.  A close flag behaves exactly as a close vote except the vote doesn't count.  And for dups also should add the "possible duplicate" comment as well, but I don't see one

Comment: @MartijnPieters, given the huge push by both community and staff to deal with the close vote queue, how can you say that a relatively easy-to-fix bug that currently hinders the ability for us to go through that queue is not worth the developer time?

Comment: @BenLee: It is an issue for a few hours when the queue is nearly empty. It'll happen another 2 times, I think? Then it'll never happen again. Why is it so hard to live with that limit for half a day?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, okay I guess I misunderstood the issue then.