# Problem with "fuzzying the number" of the Close Votes queue

Tags: discussion, bug

According to the [announcement of the burning down of the Close Votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue), the number of items in the queue has been ["fuzzied"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut) to avoid scaring people off with a daunting number that makes the task seem like trying to stop a flood with a bailing bucket.

I'm not sure exactly how the "fuzzying" is being done, but based on Shog9's explanation and the fact that the queue keeps dwindling and then suddenly jumping up by several thousand, I take it there's some kind of cyclical prioritizing process going on, in which a batch is selected according to certain criteria, and when that batch is completed, a new set of criteria is applied to select a new batch of reviews on the next rung down the priority scale.

This seems to be a good idea, but there's one problem with that approach:

[image: You done yer 20 reviews, now get lost! Don't wanna see yer face 'round here 'till tomorrow!!!]

I thought the maximum daily number of Close Votes reviews was supposed to be 40. Why was it suddenly knocked down to 20? It can't be that the bonfire was so destructive that we no longer need a higher limit in the queue, can it?

Well, apparently the higher limit isn't particular to close vote reviews; [the limit is automatically doubled for any review queue with more than 1,000 items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223917/228805).

So, whenever the number of a selected batch drops below 1,000, reviewers are temporarily capped at 20 per day until the next heaping plateful is served up. This is probably not the desired behavior when it's only the fuzzied number that's under 1,000, and there are really tens of thousands of reviews waiting in the wings. Perhaps the script should be changed to allow 40 Close Votes reviews regardless of how many items, or the next batch should be appended whenever the number drops close to 1,000?

---

**UPDATE**

@rene cleared this up in a comment, so I'm adding the explanation here. The cyclical process is simple: It's based entirely on a minimum number of close votes, and each time the queue goes to zero, a new batch is selected by reducing minimum by 1. We're now on 2 close votes and up, so it's the last cycle until the number is unfuzzied. I raised the issue because it seemed to me as if they were being served up ~10K at a time, so I thought this would keep happening over and over. Given rene's explanation, this will only happen one more time in the next 30K (the size of the new batch), so it's not a significant issue.

BTW, even though the number went up to 30K a couple of hours ago, it appears that the 20 review cap still applies to people who reached it when the number was < 1K:

[image]

I'm wondering, if someone has done more than 20 but fewer than 40 reviews when the number in queue drops below 1K, are they capped at that point, or can they continue to 40 if they've already crossed a threshold at 20? (Not really a problem or concern, just idle curiosity about how it works. Plus it's an excuse to add more freehand red circles to my post.)

Comment: This problem will be solved within (the) hour(s) when the questions with 2 votes enter the queue...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah...didn't see that because I wrote the post last night but forgot to click the "post" button until now. But, the question doesn't already have an answer there because there are no answers over there. :)

Comment: @rene The question is, will this issue keep coming back in cycles? Or does that mean we're going back to the "unfuzzied" number?

Comment: We are getting rid of a 100k+ backlog. When the backlog is gone the cycling will stop too.

Comment: The procedure was to remove the question from the queue that had 1, 2 and 3 votes. When those were handled the questions with 3 votes were added back, that is the current batch (last 80 remaining as we speak). Then the 2 votes will be added back jumping the queue up again and when that is finished the questions with 1 vote will go back in the queue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I figured. So I think it would help clear the backlog faster if the limit is changed to 40 regardless of size while we're doing this (or append new batches before the number drops under 1,000, which ever is easier codewise).

Comment: @AdiInbar: the last 1000 are cleared within a day. Just one day you can live with the limit?

Comment: @rene Oh, okay...if that's the case, this will only happen one more time, briefly, so it's not worth worrying about. I didn't know how the cycling was being done, so I thought maybe this was happening every few thousand reviews.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My concern was that maybe this was going to keep happening every few thousand reviews, over and over and over. But rene just cleared that up.

Comment: @AdiInbar: And I see Shog9 is tearing through the last handful. 67 to go and counting down rapidly.

Comment: And down to zero again.

Comment: Well that didn't last long. Up to 30.2k

Comment: Regarding your edit it was reset for me. I already hit the 20 cap earlier and can now review again. Also why does it say 4 hours? Midnight UTC is only 2 hours away.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't know. It was grayed out for me just after it went up to 30K and I had checked again shortly before posting the update. Maybe I grabbed the screen shot from a tab that was still open from when I first checked 2 hours earlier?