# "Thank you for reviewing N items" message in review dashboard doesn't reflect the actual number

Tags: bug, review

The same symptoms were already brought up in [Thank you for reviewing 20 close votes today!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223914/thank-you-for-reviewing-20-close-votes-today), but it was written off then as a one-time weirdness. This time, I request to fix this once and for all.

The message in [Review Dashboard](/review) near a queue that I cannot review more until the next day - *"Thank you for reviewing N <review type> votes today; come back in X hours to continue reviewing."* - doesn't always reflect the actual number of items that *I personally* had been stopped at. Judging by the linked question, it instead reflects some current limit on the queue or something (doesn't really matter).

---

This discrepancy causes the message to be plain wrong and thus confusing at times<sup>1</sup> which [very much looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) a bug. The text should either reflect the truth or omit the number altogether.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>More specifically, this appears to be happening when queue length fluctuates around some threshold value.</sub>

Comment: Related from MSO: [Review message says I reviewed 20, but history says I reviewed 40](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335064/review-message-says-i-reviewed-20-but-history-says-i-reviewed-40/335066#335066) as an added show that other users are indeed confused by this. Another related post: [I could review more than 20 posts, even though there were less than 150 posts in the queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332281/i-could-review-more-than-20-posts-even-though-there-were-less-than-150-posts-in) The user expresses this confusion as well, in the body of the post.